# Odd buffer exception in java

Tags: java, buffer

First my code part:

```
    public void initiate() {
    vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(30000);
    colorData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(30000);
    normalData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(30000);

    float xShift = CHUNK_WIDTH * chunkX;
    float yShift = CHUNK_HEIGHT * chunkY;
    float zShift = CHUNK_LENGTH * chunkZ;

    for(int x = 0; x < CHUNK_WIDTH; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < CHUNK_HEIGHT; y++) {
            for(int z = 0; z < CHUNK_LENGTH; z++) {
                if(blockMap[x][y][z] == Block.air.getID()) continue;

                float colorFactor = 0.9f + ((float) World.colorNoise.noise((xShift+x) / 50.0f, (yShift+y) / 50.0f, (zShift+z) / 50.0f)) / 10.0f;

                synchronized(Elevox.world.chunkMap.getChunkMap()) {
                    if(Elevox.world.chunkMap.getBlockAt((int)xShift+x+1, (int)yShift+y, (int)zShift+z).isTransparent()) {
                        colorData.put(new float[] {0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0});
                        normalData.put(new float[] {1,0,0, 1,0,0, 1,0,0, 1,0,0});
                        vertexData.put(new float[] {x+1.0f,y+0.0f,z+0.0f, x+1.0f,y+1.0f,z+0.0f, x+1.0f,y+1.0f,z+1.0f, x+1.0f,y+0.0f,z+1.0f});
                    }
                    if(Elevox.world.chunkMap.getBlockAt((int)xShift+x-1, (int)yShift+y, (int)zShift+z).isTransparent()) {
                        colorData.put(new float[] {0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0});
                        normalData.put(new float[] {-1,0,0, -1,0,0, -1,0,0, -1,0,0});
                        vertexData.put(new float[] {x+0.0f,y+0.0f,z+0.0f, x+0.0f,y+0.0f,z+1.0f, x+0.0f,y+1.0f,z+1.0f, x+0.0f,y+1.0f,z+0.0f});
                    }
                    if(Elevox.world.chunkMap.getBlockAt((int)xShift+x, (int)yShift+y+1, (int)zShift+z).isTransparent()) {
                        colorData.put(new float[] {0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0});
                        normalData.put(new float[] {0,1,0, 0,1,0, 0,1,0, 0,1,0});
                        vertexData.put(new float[] {x+0.0f,y+1.0f,z+0.0f, x+0.0f,y+1.0f,z+1.0f, x+1.0f,y+1.0f,z+1.0f, x+1.0f,y+1.0f,z+0.0f});
                    }
                    if(Elevox.world.chunkMap.getBlockAt((int)xShift+x, (int)yShift+y-1, (int)zShift+z).isTransparent()) {
                        colorData.put(new float[] {0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0});
                        normalData.put(new float[] {0,-1,0, 0,-1,0, 0,-1,0, 0,-1,0});
                        vertexData.put(new float[] {x+0.0f,y+0.0f,z+0.0f, x+1.0f,y+0.0f,z+0.0f, x+1.0f,y+0.0f,z+1.0f, x+0.0f,y+0.0f,z+1.0f});
                    }
                    if(Elevox.world.chunkMap.getBlockAt((int)xShift+x, (int)yShift+y, (int)zShift+z-1).isTransparent()) {
                        colorData.put(new float[] {0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0});
                        normalData.put(new float[] {0,0,-1, 0,0,-1, 0,0,-1, 0,0,-1});
                        vertexData.put(new float[] {x+0.0f,y+0.0f,z+0.0f, x+0.0f,y+1.0f,z+0.0f, x+1.0f,y+1.0f,z+0.0f, x+1.0f,y+0.0f,z+0.0f});
                    }
                    if(Elevox.world.chunkMap.getBlockAt((int)xShift+x, (int)yShift+y, (int)zShift+z+1).isTransparent()) {
                        colorData.put(new float[] {0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0, 0,colorFactor,0,0});
                        normalData.put(new float[] {0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1});
                        vertexData.put(new float[] {x+0.0f,y+0.0f,z+1.0f, x+1.0f,y+0.0f,z+1.0f, x+1.0f,y+1.0f,z+1.0f, x+0.0f,y+1.0f,z+1.0f});
                    }
                }

                if(vertexData.remaining() < 72) {
                    vertexData.flip();
                    vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertexData.capacity() + 1024).put(vertexData);
                }

                if(colorData.remaining() < 96) {
                    colorData.flip();
                    colorData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(colorData.capacity() + 1024).put(colorData);
                }

                if(normalData.remaining() < 72) {
                    normalData.flip();
                    normalData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(normalData.capacity() + 1024).put(normalData);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    vertexData.flip();
    colorData.flip();
    normalData.flip();

    isInitiated = true;
}
```

This piece of code runs in a thread and generates VBO data (for LWJGL). My problem is that the buffer is returning an IllegalArgumentException or BufferOverflowException which is technically impossible because he extends the buffer if it's needed. And is it even possible that the .put() method throws an IllegalArgumentException? This is not happening when i do output with System.out.println() because it slows down this code alot. This problem didn't exist before, It worked just fine and i didn't touch the code since it worked.

EDIT:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.nio.Buffer.position(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU.put(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.FloatBuffer.put(Unknown Source)
at main.Chunk.initiate(Chunk.java:104)
at main.ChunkMap.loadChunksInBounds(ChunkMap.java:111)
at main.ChunkMap$1.run(ChunkMap.java:27)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what version of JVM do you use?

Comment: Sry: line 104 is the third colorData.put() (it changes to another .put() function all the time) JVM: java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)